# Group Theory in Non-European/Subaltern Cultures?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, math-history, art

I'm doing undergraduate research on the history of Abstract Algebra (specifically permutation groups) and the notion of symmetric groups in indigenous artwork has come up several times. Is anyone aware of evidence of this 'intrinsic' human desire to construct groups I could point to? Or maybe some natural phenomena that conform to the definition of group? I'd like to have specific examples I can explain (and possibly map some ideas of formalized group theory onto). Thanks!

Comment: Could you add the references for the appearance of the symmetric group in indigenous artwork? While symmetries are certainly present in most artwork all over the work, I have serious doubts that many of the artists (independent of location) had anything group-theoretic in mind. It is a bit like saying that knot theory was present in celtic culture. While braids, tangles and knotes as an artistic objects were present as symboles, they had (to the best of my knowledge) not the slightest clue about any theoretical underpin.

Comment: You're exactly right with the knot analogy. I'm not looking to prove that earlier civilizations were onto formalized group theory; I suppose I'm more curious about what objects or systems were used/noted by people for having properties we now associate with a group. ie What groups were people working with that they didn't know/How have groups appeared before we 'discovered' them?

Comment: My professor shared one example of how Tamil Nadu Patterns are constructed symmetrically following a set of rules. I haven't researched enough to conclude whether the actions and their products could constitute a group, but its an interesting prospect. I think looking for more leads like this if anyone has ideas.

Comment: (1/3) Here are two quotes that led me down this path: “Group theory today is often described as the theory of symmetry, and indeed groups have been inherent in symmetric objects since ancient times. However, extracting algebra from a symmetric object is a highly abstract exercise, and groups first appeared in situations where some algebra was already present.” (Stillwell, 383)                                                                                                                                    Stillwell, J. (2020). Mathematics and its history: A concise edition. Springer.

Comment: (2/3) “A. Speiser emphasized symmetry in ancient ornaments as an evidence of a prehistoric group theory extending back to about 1500 B. C. It may be
desirable to note here a few evidences of a' lack of dominance of the group
concept in developments closely related thereto in order to obtain a truer
picture of the actual influence of this concept.” (Miller, 463)                          
Miller, G. A. (1931). Theorems Relating to the History of Mathematics. Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences of the United States of America, 17(8), 463–466. http://www.jstor.org/stable/85937

Comment: (3/3) The authors agree that symmetries were not formal group theory, but I'd still like to compare the art (etc.) to the more abstract groups we learn about nowadays.

Comment: I am still not quite sure what you are looking for. My guess would be that the occurence of symmetries rather motivated by esthetic reasons. In my opinion it is a bit dangerous to jump from symmetries to group theory. Otherwise you could also count any occurence of writing as group theory (free group). I feel the saves bet would be to look at the quipu. Those braids were used (as far as I know) to story numbers and even text and you could make a point that the rules (at least for the numerical values) form a group.

Comment: I cannot stress enough that I am not an expert on this and (as far as I remember) people are still analyzing those braids and it is not definitely decided what their actual meaning is. However, it might be a good starting point for your search. In any case, best of luck! I hope I did not came across as too negative in my previous comments, I am just concerned that a potential reader of your research is not willing to follow you along if your analogy for group theory is too soft.

Comment: Also apologies for my poor English, I am really tired...

Comment: Would you be satisfied with examples of symmetry, rather than group theory per se? Keep in mind, even Euclid did not make the jump to group theory, despite a spectacular intuition for symmetry underlying all of Euclid's geometric theory.

Comment: You probably know the excellent book Symmetry by Hermann Weyl. And don't forget the music. For permutations and bell chimes, see, for example, [Peal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peal).

Comment: @kabenyuk I'll look into Weyl's Symmetry. I forgot about how groups appears in change bells, I think I may include that...thank you

Comment: @LeeMosher Examples of symmetry would be great, and I see what you mean about symmetries appearing in Euclidean theories. Are you aware of any sources that tease that out? I'm not advanced enough to authoritatively analyze overarching themes of symmetry in Euclid's work myself.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven I appreciate your thoughts. I'll be mindful to present interesting symmetries not as precursors to group theory, but rather as moments where sets appeared and followed the rules of what we'd now think of as permutation groups. This is an UG-level paper so I'm not too worried about proving connection, more so creating intrigue and showing that permutation groups exist/have existed out of pure math. If anything this part the paper will err on the side of pathos rather than logos.

Answer (score 3):

You better consult *The Genesis of the Abstract Group a Contribution to the History of Abstract Group Theory: Contribution to the History of the Origin of Abstract Group Theory* by Hans Wussing, or [*Why Beauty is Truth: A History of Symmetry*](https://www.americanscientist.org/article/the-power-of-symmetry), by Ian Stewart. It turns out that only Galois, Abel, Cauchy, Lie and many others had the capability of turning symmetry (which is woven into our world) into abstract algebra/group theory.

Comment: Nice answer, though it seems to me that all the people you are mentioning are European.

Comment: Yes correct, the other countries were not that far. In France the military academies were advanced in mathematics, mechanics and engineering. Invention of book printing made a lot generally available, etc. I am not a historian but several factors (political, economical, technological and social) played a role.

Comment: I am not questioning the accuracy of your statement. It is just that the OP is looking for non-European contributions.

Comment: There aren’t any.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you if you look at the mathematical theory, but the OP is looking for examples where group theory were used in indigenous culture.

Comment: Thanks, @NickyHekster. That source sounds promising for the other part of my paper.

Comment: Good to read! Good luck finishing your paper!